# How do I change XML tag names?

Tags: 7, views

I've created views as XML data document using [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node><node>
<title>My title</title>
<field_feed_description>My description</field_feed_description>
</node></node>
```

How do I now change generated XML name tags?

For example I want to rename `field_feed_description` name into something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Views UI tick the **Create a label** checkbox and enter in your element name in the **Label** textfield. The value of **Label** will be used for the element name.

[image]